# Optimizing for loop over a large address space

Tags: c++, optimization, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug the virtual memory of a process, which requires me to search its virtual memory for a series of known and constant bytes, however due to offsets changing dynamically all the time I have to iterate over the whole address space to find the bytes I need. Currently I have these loops, which work, however they take a very long time to run ~15-30 seconds on average to complete.

```
BYTE target[15] = { 0xFG, 0x93, 0x32, 0x1A, 0xB0, 0x9F, 0xC7, 0x00, 0x11, 0x00,
                        0x3F, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    BYTE buff[15];
    int count = 0;
    DWORD target_addr = 0;
    for (DWORD i = 0x401000; i <= 0x2000000; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        ReadProcessMemory(procName, (LPCVOID)i, (LPVOID)buff, 15, &real);
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        {
            if (target[j] == buff[j])
                count++;
            else
                break;
        }
        if (count == 15)
        {
            target_addr = i;
            break;
        }
    }
```

How could I speed this process up considerably?

This is my first time using low level memory functions and the debug API of Windows so I might well be missing a far better way of doing it.

Comment: ReadProcessMemory is slow, have you tried reading more than 15 bytes at a time?  You could also use a sliding window and compare dwords instead of bytes.

Comment: You need a much bigger buffer than 15 bytes, or to mmap the process's memory into your own. Also, use `memmem()` for searching. Lastly, you aren't checking for potential overlap across blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you read 15 bytes at each iteration beginning at `i`, and if the memory is not equal, you read the 15 following bytes beginning at `i+1`, and so you do not take in count the fact that you may know the equality for the 14 other bytes. If you look the 15 bytes backward, you can know, if the buffers are not equal, if the `k`last bytes are equal, which allows to step directly `15-k` bytes forward and to not verify the `k` first bytes in the following iteration.

I have not tested the code below, but i think with this general idea, it will allow to step quicker.

```
BYTE target[15] = { 0xFG, 0x93, 0x32, 0x1A, 0xB0, 0x9F, 0xC7, 0x00, 0x11, 0x00,
                    0x3F, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
BYTE buff[15];
DWORD target_addr = 0;
DWORD current = 0x401000;
DWORD max = 0x2000000;
int previousEqual = 0;
while (!target_addr && current < max)
{
    int count = 15;
    ReadProcessMemory(procName, (LPCVOID)i, (LPVOID)buff, 15, &real);
    while (target[count-1] == buff[count-1])
    {
         --count;
    }
    if (count == previousEqual)
    {
        target_addr = current;
    }
    else
    {
        current += count;
        previousEqual = 15-count;
    }
}
```